# ARR URL Rewrite Routing Through to Wrong URL

Tags: url, url-rewriting, arr

I have setup URL Rewrite and ARR in IIS and IIS to act as a proxy server for JBoss. In Jboss i have 3 application servers, called Server1, Server2, Server3. I've managed to get the the URLs rewritten correctly for the applications in server1. However, when i try accessing an application in Server2 i can see from the failed trace logs that the new url it creates is

MyJboss1/WebReports

However i need the url to rewrite to

MyJboss2/WebReports.

As a result of it going to Server1 i get a 404 error.

I have checked the url rewrite rules, and the Rewrite URL is set as MyJboss2{R:0} with the http protocol.

I have also created a seperate server under server farms for each of the applications Servers with the different host names.

I'm not a very advanced IIS user so please do bear with me if i've not provided all the information but if u let me know anything else to help me with this issue.

Thanks